# Rails Handle Join Table UniqueViolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, upsert

I am trying to insert a row into the join table, that I created in this migration (with timestamp):

```
class CreateUserNewsItemJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :news_items do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :news_items_users, [:user_id, :news_item_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

This is how I insert NewsItem into User:

```
@user.news_items << @news_item
```

The first time, it was inserted successfully. But if I insert the same record again, it shows UniqueViolation.

How can I make the identical insert, to update timestamp, instead of throwing UniqueViolation error?

Comment: You are trying to do an *upsert* . It's not as simple as you'd think. For some non-Rails-specific info, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17267417/398670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to insert again, you want to update the join table.

According to the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many) If you need to work with the join table at all, it should have it's own model:

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many
>   :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model
>   as an independent entity. If you don't need to do anything with the
>   relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a
>   has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you'll need to remember
>   to create the joining table in the database).

Therefore, create the model and use a has_many_through.

You'll then be able to do:

```
item = UserNewsItem.find_by(news_id: x, user: y)
item.update_attribute(:updated_at, Time.now)
```

Comment: Thanks, I end up creating a model, like your suggestion. But I used this:

read = Read.find_or_initialize_by(:user_id => @user.id, :news_item_id => news_item.id).update_attributes(:updated_at => Time.now)